# Receiving a 404 exception in apache logs while using Kryo(Serialization technique) in application

Tags: java, serialization

I am using Kryo 1.03 version in my Application. I am using FeildSerializer class in Kryo to register the POJO's in my application. My Application is using Applets as GUI and servlets at the backend and deployed on Weblogic10.3 server

When Launching the application, we download all the jars from the Server to the client Side. In this scenario, we are using FeildSerializer to register the POJO class. I see the following line of error in access.log file of Apache.

kryo.register(CurrencyStruct.class, new FieldSerializer(kryo,CurrencyStruct.class));

"GET CurrencyStructFieldAccess.class HTTP/1.1" 404 262

Applet is trying to search for CurrencyStructFieldAccess.class and is not able to find the class and is calling the GET request to call the above class on the server.

Because of the above issue, we are getting a popup with the Security exception while launching.
Can someone please help me to resolve the issue of Applets not calling the server side for the specified class and also how this particular class(*FieldAccess.class) is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about other issues, but FieldAccess is something generated using [ReflectASM](http://code.google.com/p/reflectasm/) library, which is used to do more efficient field/method access than default reflection access: it can generate XxxFieldAccess and XxxMethodAccess classes using byte code generation. This is probably something that makes Kryo very efficient for serialization and deserialization.

If the code is run on applet, the problem is that generated class must be used with a custom class loader; and this is something that must get permission from security manager.